# Facebook C# Api: Get comment and like data from a post

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've tried the following:

This is the post I'm trying to retrieve : http://www.facebook.com/TeapotParty/posts/134801493258490

```
var fbc = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic post = fbc.Get("/TeapotParty/posts/134854426586530");
```

and

```
dynamic streams = fbc.Query("select text from comment  where post_id  = " + 134801493258490);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, but need to be logged in as that user

```
dynamic stream = fbc.Query("select post_id from stream where permalink  = 'http://www.facebook.com/TeapotParty/posts/134801493258490'");"select post_id from stream where permalink  = 'http://www.facebook.com/TeapotParty/posts/134801493258490'");
```

Comment: which user? The one that posted the post or the comment?